# How to clean up the smell of egg from a pot?

Tags: eggs, smell

When I cook eggs, the smell spreads to other dishes, such as glasses or cups. This is very embarrassing. I used hot water to wash them, but failed to remove the smell.  How do I clean them to remove it?

Comment: boil some baking soda + water  in the pot/pan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of lingering egg smell from eggs. Is there a possibility that there is a certain amount of sulfur content in your water?

> Sulfur water (or sulphur water) is a condition where the running water contains a high amount of hydrogen sulfide gas that escapes into the air when the plumbing line is opened, giving a distinct "rotten egg" smell.
>
> The condition indicates a high level of sulfate-reducing bacteria in the water supply. This may be due to the use of well water, poorly treated city water, or water heater contamination.

[Wikipedia: Sulfur water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_water)

Comment: Either that or you keep your eggs way too long..